# Diffusion coefficient as a function of distance from the position autocorrelation function

Tags: molecular-dynamics, molecular-modeling, correlation-functions

I am trying to understand if my idea for the computation of diffusion coefficient as a function of distance is right or not. So, the diffusion coefficient as a function of distance is given by,
$$D(z) = \frac{\mathrm{var}(z)}{\tau}$$
Here, I am calculating the diffusion coefficient for the motion of a solute when the solute is restrained to some position along the transmembrane coordinate $z$ by a harmonic potential ([Umbrella Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbrella_sampling)).

So, if I fit the position autocorrelation function with $e^\frac{-t}{\tau}$, it should give me autocorrelation time $\tau$ which I can plug in the above equation to compute the diffusion coefficient for that particular restrained position. Am I following correctly? Thanks.

Comment: How did this go Roshan? Have you found an answer?

Comment: Hi @NikeDattani, I have. Actually, we've published the results here as well :-) https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jpcb.2c02007

Comment: Why don't you write an answer to this question? We have over 300 questions in the unanswered queue, and it would be nice to clear it up!

Comment: Thanks, I will do as you've suggested.

Comment: Any update on this? We like to scan through the unanswered questions periodically to see if there are any that have either become answerable in the interim or which the user is no longer interested in.